# OverGrive does not launch

Tags: 16.04, google-drive

The command `python /opt/thefanclub/overgrive/overgrive` results in this output:

```
                      ____      _             
  _____   _____ _ __ / ___|_ __(_)_   _____   
 / _ \ \ / / _ \ '__| |  _| '__| \ \ / / _ \  
| (_) \ V /  __/ |  | |_| | |  | |\ V /  __/  
 \___/ \_/ \___|_|   \____|_|  |_| \_/ \___|  
                      Google Drive for Linux
  version 3.2.3 beta

  by The Fan Club - Copyright (c) 2014-2016   
          http://www.thefanclub.co.za         

[INFO] Linux-4.4.0-41-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
[INFO] Desktop : ubuntu
[CONFIG] Loading User Settings GUI mode
[CONFIG] Auto Sync : True
[CONFIG] Convert Google Docs : False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "overgrive.py", line 5948, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Even with the last version. I tried to comment on the same issue on other question but it seems that I do not have enough "reputation" for it.

I tried `sudo pip2 install --upgrade google-api-python-client` but it says:

> You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.

But if I try `pip install --upgrade pip`, it says:

> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in
>   ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Answer (score 4):

I got in contact with thefanclub and Christiaan Diedericks kindly answered with a solution that actually works! It is as follows:

> Make sure you use the latest version 3.2.3 from our website : https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive
>
> Clear all trashed files from your Google Drive online Trash/Bin
>   folder.
>
> Delete the following files from your local Google Drive folder restart
>   the program.
>
> - .overgrive.cache
> - .overgrive.auth
>
> You will find the setup screen again. Do the setup and click "Start
>   Sync"
>
> It does not download all the files again. It just "checks" every file
>   and rebuilds the local cache file. It takes time, but no files will be
>   downloaded if they exist already.
>
> You have to wait for the sync to complete before making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: the local Google Drive Folder is the folder where the files are synchronized by Overgrive. In this file the option HIDDEN FILES must be enabled, only with this option enabled the files overgrive.cache and overgrive.auth are visibles for to be deleted.